# Python 3.6.4 dbus import error

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, dbus

After adding /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages to my sys.path as someone suggested in another post, I am now getting the error when I try to import dbus in python3:

```
>>> import dbus
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    import dbus.types as types
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/types.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _dbus_bindings import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dbus_bindings'
```

I've tried reinstalling python3-dbus with apt, but to no avail. I even had to reinstall my operating system after accidentally uninstalling dbus instead of python3-dbus while trying to completely reset my python3-dbus. I even installed Python 3.6.4 from source. Any help is appreciated because I'm completely lost as to why this isn't working.

The files in my /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/dbus/ directory:

```
bus.py         exceptions.py                lowlevel.py  service.py
_compat.py     _expat_introspect_parser.py  mainloop     types.py
connection.py  gi_service.py                proxies.py   _version.py
_dbus.py       glib.py                      __pycache__
decorators.py  __init__.py                  server.py
```

It seems to me like python is trying to import from the file _dbus_bindings.py but it doesn't exist. I've looked at this error online and coulnd't find anything useful.

Answer (score 3):

I have solved this problem by:

```
pip3 install dbus-python
```

Comment: Underrated answer. If you can't do this then your problem is your package repo.

Answer (score 1):

If you have packet 'python3.6' installed via ppa like it is explained here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts, then you can just switch the command python3 back to point to python of version 3.5 using the command:

sudo update-alternatives --config python3

I had problem with launching unity-tweak-tool which relies on python 3.5 and gave me the "No module named '_dbus_bindings'" error. And this solution helped, though it deprives you of python 3.6.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and tried `pip install dbus-python` and `pip3 install dbus-python` as suggested for this "import dbus" error, but kept getting error. Placing the "import dbus" below "sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")" resolved the issue.So,

```
# Below line gave import dbus error!
import dbus   
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
```

The issue got fixed after placing "import dbus" below "sys.path..":

```
# This worked
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages")
import dbus
```